# Angular and Devise permission error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, angularjs, devise

I'm using Angular and Devise for my webapp and I'm having a small problem. I don't want user to visit certain parts of the app unless they are signed in, so I use `before_action :authenticate_user!` in my application_controller.rb.

I've used router-ui to route users to #home when they visit the page, http://localhost:3000/users/sign_in#/home

```
$stateProvider
  .state('home', {
    url: '/home',
    templateUrl: '../assets/angular-app/templates/_home.html.haml',
    controller: 'mainCtrl',
    resolve: {
      postPromise: ['posts', function(posts){
        return posts.getAll();
      }]
    }
  })
```

the resolve retrieves all the posts from my database and outputs it on the homepage. But when a user is not logged in the JSON file gives a 401 authorization failure, since he's not logged in.

What would be the best way to fix this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the controller when you retrieve the posts you should skip `authenticate_user!` filter for the action that responds the request.

```
class YourController < ApplicationController

  skip_before_action :authenticate_user!, only: :your_action

  def your_action
    # the action which retrieves posts
  end
  ...
end
```